# Error BUILD FAILED on Titanium 3.1.3.201309132423 on Mac OS 10.8.5

Tags: macos, module, titanium

I am trying to build an empty java module on Titanium 3.1.3. 
I have installed all prerequisites but I still get the following error:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/simon/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.3.GA/module/android/build.xml:326: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/simon/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.1.3.GA/module/android/build.xml:281: exec returned: 2

I was looking for solutions but did find anything that helped resolving this issue..

Thanks,
 Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install Command Line Tools?

Go to XCode, press "Cmd + ," and click on "Downloads". Check if Command Line Tools is installed, otherwise install them and thy to type "gperf -v" in terminal window. You should get some output there.

Comment: Command line tools are installed but gperf -v returns "command not found".

Comment: I thought command line tools were installed. Command line tools were not installed. I have installed and that fixed the problem. THANKS!!!